# After Spring Security login, I'm redirected to a CSS/JS resource instead of a HTML page

Tags: jsf, redirect, authentication, spring-security

I have a project with spring-security and PrimeFaces and I got an error, when I execute my project.

this URL always appear `/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1`

This happens, when I overwrite this method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml")
        .permitAll();
}
```

and put my own login page.
However my web.xml call the page home.xhtml

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

That's what it shows up is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAaZ8.png):

[image]

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: The erro is that the page with all css /javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1 show up instead my home.xhtml

Comment: What happens when you go to `home.xhtml`?

Comment: if i go manually to home.xhtml the page works fine. but the erros is after click on login button and then is automatically to the with javascript and css

Answer (score 19):

The login will by default redirect to the last requested restricted resource of the current HTTP session. Apparently you've (unawarely) also covererd JS/CSS/image resources of JSF-generated HTML pages as restricted resources. When the login page itself references exactly that JavaScript file, then it would be remembered as last requested restricted resource and Spring Security would then blindly redirect to it after successful login.

You need to tell Spring Security to exclude them from restricted resources. One way would be adding the below line to the Spring Security XML configuration file.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" filters="none"/>
```

Another way would be to override `SecurityConfig#configure(WebSecurity)`.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**");
}
```

This should also immediately solve all broken CSS/JS/images on the login page itself (which you should have noticed by checking the browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor and/or JS console when loading the login page).

Comment: How i do this with Annotations? Because i don't have this spring-xml configuration file.

Comment: I also found out the hard way that order matters. You need to have antMatcher that allows access to those resources to be the first one in the configuration.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Is it possible, though, to restrict access to Javascript resources (from security reasons) as well, but avoid this redirection?

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful for me. I overrided SecurityConfig#configure(WebSecurity) and added "/css/**","/js/**"

Comment: @BalusC you mentioned `default redirect to the last requested restricted resource of the current HTTP session` - how to stop this so that after successful login user will be redirected to the page as configured in the spring security configuration.

Comment: A little update: The answer didn't work for me and lead to an error of "type=null" and "status=null", but it did point me in the right direction: adding the path to the resource that was requested (in my case, the js-file) to my antMatchers solved the issue.